# net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED For a Route that is clearly defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fetch

This is most likely a typo somewhere, and if it is, I apologize, but I can't seem to find where. I send a POST fetch to "http://localhost3006/players/update_or_create" and I have it properly formatted in my routes.rb file like so...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'players/update_or_create', to: 'players#update_or_create'
end
```

But the fetch fails, I'm assuming because it cannot find the route that is clearly defined (controllers are also properly set up)
The file where I call the dispatch looks as so...

```
import DOMAIN from "../constants/domain"

//DOMAIN() will return "http://localhost3006"

// This is imported by AttributeSelection.js
export default function completeAttributeSelection(playerObj){
    const playerPOST = ({
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            atk: playerObj.atk,
            sAtk: playerObj.sAtk,
            def: playerObj.def,
            sDef: playerObj.sDef,
            spd: playerObj.spd,
            hp: playerObj.hp,
            name: playerObj.name
        })
    })
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: "LOADING"})
        console.log("Domain: " + DOMAIN())
        fetch((DOMAIN() + "/players/update_or_create"), playerPOST)
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json)
                dispatch({type: "ATTRIBUTE_UPDATE_COMPLETE", payload: json})
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a column (`:`) after `http://localhost`. It's a DNS issue not a rails router one.

This:

```
//DOMAIN() will return "http://localhost3006"
```

Has to return this:

```
//DOMAIN() will return "http://localhost:3006"
```